# Confused by `object` type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to come up with a type signature for a function parameter that itself is a function with a single parameter of type any *object*. Like this ([typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20aaa(a%3A%20%7Bn%3A%20number%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bbb(fn%3A%20(a%3A%20object)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Abbb(aaa))):

[image]

But in the strict compiler mode I am getting this error:

```
Argument of type '(a: { n: number; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: object) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ n: number; }'.
      Property 'n' is missing in type '{}'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`bbb` expects a function that can be called with any object as argument.

You're passing `aaa` as argument. But `aaa` can only be called with objects which have a property `n` of type number. It can't be called with any kind of object. So it's not a valid argument for `bbb`.

To make an analogy, `bbb` is like a juice bar, which needs a fruit juicer to work, i.e. a function that can take *any* fruit and tranform it to juice.

If you try to create a juice bar with an apple juicer (i.e. a function that can only make juice out of apples), that won't work well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! So what is the correct way to express "accept a function with a single parameter of any object"?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean, but I guess you want `function bbb(fn: (a: any) => void)`

Comment: Perhaps it will be a bit better to go generic: `function bbb<T extends object>(fn: (a: T) => void)` - can't test it right now, though.

Comment: However, if I turn it to this I am still getting the same error `type Fn = <T extends object>(a: T) => void;

function ccc(fn: Fn) { };

ccc(aaa)
`